# Remove duplicate AND original values, leaving only truly unique values

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I've found millions of ways to show only the unique values in a range of cells, but nothing for this. What I want to do is compare two cells (or ranges) and return ONLY the values that were not duplicated. I.e., if the two cells contain the words Ursine and Bovine, it would return `URSBOV` the e,n, and i removed.

Ex.

```
Column 1----column 2---column 3(result)
"Ursine"-------"Bovine"-----"URSBOV"
"Canine"------"Feline"-------"FLCA"
```

Comment: What have you tried? This will likely require VBA if you're comparing the characters in a cell to the characters in another cell.

Comment: I figured as much, but lack the skills myself. Usually I can Google up some VBA to copy-paste, but it hasn't worked on this problem. (Haven't really tried anything, since everything I've found is pretty clear that it's returning all unique values (above example would result in URSINEBOV).

Comment: Show some example

Comment: If column1 has "hello" and B has "help", what do you expect as output, "op" or "lop"?

Comment: This would be a sinch if you have MS Access, a database program. A simple query. This is a query you are asking for, FYI.

Comment: "Hello" and "help" would turn into "op".

Comment: Maybe I need to look into Access...

Comment: You can do this in Excel with helper columns (and without VBA) if you have a limited number of columns to compare and shortish strings (len<100).

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA routine works, although I would imagine a more efficient algorithm exists.

It is written as a function.

- Combine the two strings into one
- Does first character exist more than once in the string
- If not, check the next character
- If it does, delete all the matching characters
- Repeat until all the characters have been checked

I use a recursive sub to do this, with which I don't have much experience. But it does seem to return the desired output.

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Function UniqueChars(s1 As String, s2 As String)
   Dim S As String
S = s1 & s2
RemoveDups S, 1
UniqueChars = UCase(S)
End Function

Sub RemoveDups(ByRef S As String, ByVal NDX As Long)
    Dim Ltr As String * 1
    If NDX > Len(S) Then Exit Sub
    Ltr = Mid(S, NDX)
    If Len(S) = Len(Replace(S, Ltr, "")) + 1 Then 'unique character
        NDX = NDX + 1
    Else
        S = Replace(S, Ltr, "")
    End If

    RemoveDups S, NDX
End Sub
```

---

Note that if you don't want to use `Option Compare Text` for the module, you can specify the compare mode as an optional argument individually in the VBA `Replace` function.  I'm not sure which is more efficient.

[image]